# Jquery find if element contains more than specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to check if an text input contains certain information, beyond a set text known to me.

The code below will execute if the words "/search: " is in the text input.

```
tactopiaUniversalSearch = function(e) {
 $('#Search').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {

  var searchVar = jQuery('#Search').val();    

  if (searchVar.indexOf('/search: ') >= 0) {
   //doing stuff
  }

});
```

But how do I check if *any* other text (written by a user) is present in the textbox, ie "/search: *tags*" or "/search: *photos*" or "/search: *whatever user wants*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use .replace on the target search value if the string includes the target search value -> `/search:` .

```js
$('#search').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {

  var searchVar = $('#search').val();

  if (searchVar.includes('/search: ')) {
    let opt = searchVar.replace('/search: ', '');
    console.log(opt)
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search">
<button id="searchBtn">search</button>
```

Comment: Replace is a good suggestion for getting the unknown text, but `.includes()` isn't good because it will always be true. You could move `let opt = searchVar.replace('/search: ', '');` before the if statement, and then check `if (opt.length) { }`.

Comment: You could also use: `if (searchVar.indexOf('/search: ') !== -1)` as 'The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.'

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression might work for you.

```
tactopiaUniversalSearch = function(e) {
 $('#Search').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {

  var searchVar = jQuery('#Search').val();    

  if (/\/search: \w+/.test(searchVar) {
   //doing stuff
  }

});
```

That conditional will be true for any string starting with "search: " followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters. For more explanation about `.test()` see this reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String **includes** function:

`if(searchVar.includes('/search: '))`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: I don't think so. That will always be true because he specifies that the string always starts with "/search: ", so it is true even if there is no additional input.